# Change format date

Tags: php, date

I have date in format "m-Y-d". How can i modify this date to format "Y-d-m"? For this the best should be function where i can add old format and new format, but how can i make it?

For example i have

```
$date = '01-2013-13'; // "m-Y-d"
```

i would like receive:

```
$newDate = '2013-13-01'; // "Y-d-m"
```

Comment: `date('new format', strtotime($date));`

Comment: @WaleedKhan - Is that originating date format a standard date that `strtotime` can parse? Also, I believe `strtotime('01-02-2013')` will parse differently than `strtotime('01/02/2013')`, the first giving `February 2, 2013`, the latter `January 1, 2013`.

Comment: This is an extremely basic question and I cannot believe that a web search for "php format date" did not point you to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y-d', '01-2013-13');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot parse the format using `strtotime()`. You'll have to do something like this:

```
function reformat($old_date)
{
    $parts = explode('-', $old_date);
    return $parts[1].'-'.$parts[2].'-'.$parts[0];
}
```

And then call it using:

```
$new_format = reformat($date);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
function reformat($old_date)
{
    $new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y-d', $old_date);
    return $new_date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime` class, for example:

```
$date = new DateTime('01-2013-13');
```

Then use the `format()` method, like:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

More info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: I'd be inclined to use `createFromFormat` rather than the plain `DateTime` constructor, since the incoming format is known in advance. It's also unusual and potentially ambiguous, so having PHP guess what the format is probably isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

To create you need to use:

```
$newDate = date('Y-d-m');
```

You can find more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)!